# Bloc event not receiving data?

Tags: flutter, bloc

Im currently having issues with my first bloc made from 0, it supposed to throw an error once a number reaches a certain number, but i noticed through testing that the event is not receiving any data at all, i have no idea what im doing wrong.

I can confirm that the event is being triggered, on changed the textfield fires the event.

I dont know if it matters yet but if try to int.parse it i recieve null.

Widget with the string that should be sent to the event.

```
class Daytextfield extends StatelessWidget {
  Daytextfield({
    Key? key,
    required this.digits,
    required this.hint,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int digits;
  final String hint;
  final String texto = '';
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final TextEditingController dias = TextEditingController(text: texto);
    Color color = Colors.black;
    

    return BlocConsumer<DaysBloc, DaysState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if(state is DaysIncorrectState){
          color = Colors.red;
        } else if (state is DaysCorrectState){
          color = Colors.green;
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            
            BlocProvider.of<DaysBloc>(context).add(DaysChangedEvent(texto: texto));
           print(state);
          //  var ree = int.tryParse(texto);
           print(texto);
          },
          controller: dias,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          cursorColor: Color.fromARGB(148, 66, 63, 63),
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline1!
              .copyWith(fontSize: 20, color: color),
```

Blocs

```
class DaysBloc extends Bloc<DaysEvent, DaysState> {
  int max = 360;

  DaysBloc() : super(DaysInitial()) {
    on<DaysChangedEvent>((event, emit) {
      if(event.texto == '123') {emit(DaysIncorrectState(texto: event.texto));}
      else emit(DaysCorrectState(texto: event.texto));


    });
  }
}
```

```
abstract class DaysEvent extends Equatable {
  const DaysEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class DaysChangedEvent extends DaysEvent {
String texto;

  DaysChangedEvent({
    required this.texto,
  });
  
@override
  List<Object> get props => [texto];

}
```

```
class DaysInitial extends DaysState {}

class DaysCorrectState extends DaysState {

 String texto;
 

  DaysCorrectState({
    required this.texto,
    
  });

@override
  List<Object> get props => [texto];
}

class DaysIncorrectState extends DaysState {

 String texto;
 

  DaysIncorrectState({
    required this.texto,
   
  });

@override
  List<Object> get props => [texto];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`BlocProvider.of<DaysBloc>(context).add(DaysChangedEvent(texto: texto));`

with

`BlocProvider.of<DaysBloc>(context).add(DaysChangedEvent(texto: value));`

`texto` is a final empty string hence you might be receiving empty string as event every time.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
BlocProvider.of<DaysBloc>(context).add(DaysChangedEvent(texto: texto));
```

replace `(texto:texto)` with `(texto:value)`

So It will look like this

```
BlocProvider.of<DaysBloc>(context).add(DaysChangedEvent(texto: value));
```

That should do the work.